# SpringSecurity "Full authentication is required to access this resource" / JWT Token / Access API after login

Tags: java, authentication

I am using SpringSecurity and JSON Webtoken to authenticate to my Backend. To test my API i use Postman.
I am able to Register. (Response: 200)
I am able to Login. (Respons: 200 + BearerToken)
I am not(!) able to request any other entry point. (Response: 401 Unauthorized)

The error Message is: "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Parts of my POM:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Security configuration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    // Token Entry Point

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthentificationEntryPoint jwtAuthentificationEntryPoint;

    // Token Filter

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthentificationFilter jwtAuthentificationFilter(){
        return new JwtAuthentificationFilter();
    }

    // Passwort Encoder

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    // Filter Chain

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        log.info("-----> Filterchain called! ");
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthentificationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

My authentication Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

private UserRepository userRepository;

private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

public AuthController(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
}

@PostMapping(value = "/register")
public ResponseEntity<UserEntity> register(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest){
    Optional<UserEntity> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail(authRequest.getEmail());

    if(userOptional.isPresent()){
        log.info("User {} existiert bereits",authRequest.getEmail());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }

    UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
    user.setEmail(authRequest.getEmail());
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(authRequest.getPassword()));

    UserEntity createdUser = userRepository.save(user);
    log.info("Benutzer {} erfolgreich registriert", user.getEmail());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(createdUser);
}

@PostMapping(value = "/login")
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest){
    log.info("Login Request {}", authRequest.getEmail());
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getEmail(), authRequest.getPassword()));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(jwtTokenProvider.generiereToken(authentication));
}
```

}

AuthenticationEntryPoint

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthentificationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.info("jwtEntryPoint called");
    log.info(String.valueOf("---------- request getUserPrincipal ----------"));
    log.info(String.valueOf(request.getUserPrincipal()));
    log.info(String.valueOf("---------- request getRequestURL ----------"));
    log.info(String.valueOf(request.getRequestURL()));
    log.info(String.valueOf("---------- request getMethod ----------"));
    log.info(String.valueOf(request.getMethod()));
    log.info(String.valueOf("---------- response Status ----------"));
    log.info(String.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
    log.info(String.valueOf("---------- authException ----------"));
    log.info(String.valueOf(authException));
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

}

JWTAuthenticationFilter

```
public class JwtAuthentificationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.info("dofilter im JwtAuthenticationFilter called.");
    String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);
    if(StringUtils.hasText(jwt) &&  jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)){
        log.info("---------- Bedingung true ----------");
        //log.info(jwt);
        //log.info(String.valueOf(jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)));
    }
    else {
        log.info("---------- Bedingung false ----------");
        //String.valueOf(jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwt));
    }
    if(StringUtils.hasText(jwt) &&  jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)){
        String mail = jwtTokenProvider.getUserMailFromToken(jwt);
        log.info("---------- mail ----------");
        log.info(mail);
        UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(mail);
        log.info(String.valueOf("---------- userDetails ----------"));
        log.info(String.valueOf(userDetails));
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
        log.info(String.valueOf("---------- authentication ----------"));
        log.info(String.valueOf(authentication));
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
}

private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
    log.info("getJwtTokenFromRequest called.");
    log.info("---------- Request Header ----------");
    log.info(String.valueOf(request.getHeader("Authorization")));
    String bearertoken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (StringUtils.hasText(bearertoken) && bearertoken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
        log.info("Bearer Token in getJwtFromRequest konnte ermittelt werden.");
        return bearertoken.substring(7);
    }
    log.error("Bearer Token in getJwtFromRequest konnte nicht ermittelt werden.");
    log.info("---------- Token ----------");
    log.info(bearertoken);
    return null;
}
```

}

JWTTokenProvider

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

@Value("{$app.jwtsecret}")
private String jwtSecret;

public String generiereToken(String userEmail){
    Instant jetzt = Instant.now();
    Instant ablauf = jetzt.plus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

    return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(userEmail)
            .setIssuedAt(Date.from(jetzt))
            .setExpiration(Date.from(ablauf))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
            .compact();
}

public String generiereToken(Authentication authentication){
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    return generiereToken(user.getUsername());
}

public String getUserMailFromToken(String token){
    Claims claims = Jwts
            .parser()
            .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();

    return claims.getSubject();
}

public boolean validateToken(String token){
    try{
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token);
        return true;
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.info("Token abgelaufen");
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.info("Token nicht supported.");
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.info("MalformedJwtException");
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.info("Signatur ungültig");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.info("IllegalArgumentException");
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

The entry point i try to call after successful login

```
@RestController
public class aktivitaetenAPI {

@Autowired
AktivitaetenService aktivitaetenService;

@GetMapping("/getall")
public List<AktivitaetenEntity> getAll(){
    log.info("getall request");
    return aktivitaetenService.findAll();
}
```

}

I am really happy for any answers.
Thanks in advance!

Daniel

Comment: share your url details which are working which are not working.

Comment: This one does not work: http://localhost:8080/getall The working entpoints are: http://localhost:8080/auth/register and http://localhost:8080/auth/login